# How to remove Tags: text from the_tags?

Tags: tags

The function `the_tags();` gives output as: `Tags: tag1, tag2`. But I want to get the tags only without the text `Tags:`. How can I use the function so that it does not out the text`? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like `<?php the_tags('', ', ', '<br />'); ?>`

From Wordpress codex for [the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags):

```
<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

> **Parameters**
>
> **$before** 
>        (string) Text to display before the actual tags are displayed. Defaults to Tags:
>
> **$sep** 
>        (string) Text or character to display between each tag link. The default is a comma (,) between each tag.
>
> **$after**
>       (string) Text to display after the last tag. The default is to display nothing.